# How to convert a Json whose fields change depending on the parameters to a Gson?

Tags: json, android-studio, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

Im using retrofit and i'm trying to convert a dynamic Json to a Gson but the fields of the Json change depending on the parameters.For example if i have parameters 1,2

JSON format:

```
{  
   "data":{  
  "1":{  
     "urls":{  
        "website":[  
           "https://bitcoin.org/"
        ],
        "source_code":[  
           "https://github.com/bitcoin/"
        ]
     },
     "logo":"https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/1.png"
     ... 

  },
  "2":{  
     "urls":{  
        "website":[  
           "https://litecoin.org/"
        ],
        "source_code":[  
           "https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin"
        ]
     },
     "logo":"https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/2.png"
     ...
      }
   }
}
```

Note that it is possible to have any number of parametrs.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, instead of having the type of 'data' be an object, you could make it an array like so:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      ...
    },
    {
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, when you're dealing with your 'data' element, you can easily check the length and see how many there are. Assuming you have parsed your Json already and have access to 'data', the Java code for doing something with that data would look like this:

```
JsonArray array = dataElement.getAsJsonArray();
for(JsonElement element : array){
    JsonObject object = element.getAsJsonObject();
    String logo = object.getAsJsonPrimitive("logo").getAsString();
    ...
}
```

If that isn't possible, then you'd have to do something like this:

```
JsonObject dataObject = ...
int i = 1;
while(true){
    JsonElement element = dataObject.get("" + i);
    if(!element.isJsonObject()){
        break;
    }
    JsonObject object = element.getAsJsonObject();
    // do stuff with object
    i++;
}
```